# Client Credentials OAuth2 in Android

Tags: java, android, api, oauth, android-library

I have an App that consumes an API.

The API uses OAuth2 and I would like to use a library to deal with OAuth for me.
I have a CLIENT_ID and a CLIENT_SECRET and the grant type is "client_credentials".

Currently, I am doing everything on my own: using HttpUrlConnection, I request a token and I save it. I add the token to the headers of the HttpUrlConnections of the next calls and it works alright.

I would like to make a module that wraps the API and that allows for an easier change of grant type in the future and for that **I need an OAuth2 lib that supports implicit and client credentials grant types, with some guidance on how to use it.**

What I have tried:

- [oauth java client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2), but I cannot understand how to even begin using it.
- [scribe](https://github.com/scribejava/scribejava), but it seems to be focused on the implicit grant and that is not available to me right now.
- [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), which I would like to avoid for now.